# How to print multiple words from same line in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been using this Perl regex script for a while now:

```
open DOC1, "<", "list.txt" or die $!;
open DOC2, "> list.xls";
while (my $lines = <DOC1>) {
        if ($lines =~ m/([^\s]+(([a-z0-9._%+-]+\@)|([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15}(\.|\-|_)[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15})))/i) {
        print DOC2 lc($1), "\n";
    }
}
close DOC2;
close DOC1;
```

It works fine, but recently I've realized that it prints only the first match in each line. Once it finds a match and prints it, it jumps to the next line without further checking the current line.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks to me you're trying to match email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `g` modifier (g for global, which saves your position in the string after a match is made, and allows you to find multiple matches), and then perform the regex in a `while` loop instead of an `if`. Try this:

```
open DOC1, "<", "list.txt" or die $!;
open DOC2, "> list.xls";
while (my $lines = <DOC1>) {
    while ($lines =~ m/([^\s]+(([a-z0-9._%+-]+\@)|([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15}(\.|\-|_)[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15})))/gi) {
        print DOC2 lc($1), "\n";
    }
}
close DOC2;
close DOC1;
```